# Finding min value of float from a large dataset giving wrong answer

Tags: java, min

I have to find out min value from a large dataset of 3.1M of some user's salary to run an experiment of my thesis work. Data is given in following format in a text file -

```
0024000
0070000
9999999
0079500
0091500
```

Every data is positive.

I am trying to find out min using `Math.min`. But the result is given a negative number but data doesn't contain any negative number.

Can anyone please explain what I am doing wrong?
 Here is the code-

```
public void readFile()
{
    double max=Double.MIN_VALUE;
    double min=Double.MAX_VALUE ;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ipum_data.txt"));
        int id=1;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            User user=new User();
            user.id=id;
            user.salary=Double.parseDouble(line);
            if(user.salary<=0.0) continue;
            else
            {
                userList.add(user);
                id++;
                actual_total_salary+=user.salary;
                max=Math.max(max, user.salary);            
                min=Math.min(min,user.salary);                     
            }                
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("max salary "+max);
    System.out.println("min salary "+min);
}
```

Comment: It could be that you are overflowing the capacity of the `float` type. What happens if you use `double` instead?

Comment: Why don't use Integer?

Answer (score 1):

Use Float.MAX_VALUE for initialiZing or use a double in which case use Double.MAX_VALUE .

Comment: I tried both. But gives same answer min= -12800.0 @dev8080. But file doesn't contain this data. It's a simple thing but didn't work. I use the similar  method to find max but it works :(

Comment: @Mousumi, You say the file doesn't contain that value.  Have you personally looked at all 3.1 million lines?  If not, why don't you add some logic to your code that will _tell_ you if it reads a negative number.  Hint:  It would be helpful if it also told you the line number where the negative appeared.

Comment: @james large I had assumed it should be positive as salary data should not be negative:( it was the mistake. Thanks a lot. It works when I add this line. if(user.salary<=0.0) continue;